# How to export a SheetJS worksheet with correct date formatting as JSON?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

## The task

Our application is a reporting tool which displays values as a table. We want an import/export interface with Excel. The data to export is supplied by the backend via JSON. I want to use SheetJS to convert that data to a worksheet and then create an `.xlsx` file out it. A typical table might look like this

| Name | 01.03.2020 | 01.04.2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some Values | 1.00 | -4.5 |
| Some Other Values | 3% | 10% |

## The issue

The problem arises when tryin to export such a table as JSON. The `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` method converts the dates (internally the cells have type `d` (date)) in the header row to `mm/dd/yy` format:

```
[  
  { 
    "Name": "Some Values",
    "3/1/20": 1.0,
    "4/1/20": -4.5
  },
  {
    "Name": "Some Other Values",
    "3/1/20": 0.03,
    "4/1/20": 0.1  
  }
]
```

Calling `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` with the `cellDates: True, dateNF: 'dd.mm.yyyy'` options does not help. I would like the json to maintain the date format.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using `sheet_to_json` if you are intending to generate an Excel spreadsheet as an output. Wouldn't you use `json_to_sheet` ?

Comment: I needed both directions so from JSON to Excel and from Excel to JSON. The "solution" I arrived at was using the standard ISO Date Format and formatting the excel as a date cell. Due to localization Excel displayed the dates in the `dd.mm.yyyy`, the way our users expect it to. When re-importing an excel sheet the parser correctly identifies the date cells. In the end I also needed to some manual tweaking as our backend also provided format strings for the value cells. I set those using the `z` field. Digging around in the documentaion helped.